# Check for existing user using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware

I'm trying to write a middleware function that (when a POST request is made with a username/password) checks to see if the user being created already exists in the database. I don't know if I'm doing this properly though.

`User.find({ username: req.body.username })` returns an object which contains (or does not contain) the user if it exists...but how to properly `return` to exit if a user under the same username is found? Whenever I test this with Mocha, res.body.msg comes up as undefined.

Code:

```
module.exports = exports = function(req, res, next) {
  User.find({ username: req.body.username }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return handleDBError(err, res);
    if (user) return res.status(200).json({ msg: 'an account with this username already exists' });
  });
  next();
};
```

User Schema:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  authentication: {
    email: String,
    password: String
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

give it a try very initial create a function to get the `user` response

```
function findUser(arg, callback) {
  /* write your query here */
  return callback(pass response here)
}
```

And then use it where you want

```
findUser(arg,function(callbackResponse) { /*do something*/ })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nodejs is asynchronous, chances are that the response is being sent after you are trying to read it. Make sure to keep the reading process waiting untill response is sent. I personaly use passport for handling that.